# Clearing Archive bit for android

Tags: java, android, cordova, filesystems

On reading file, how to clear file archive bit using java for  an android application.

I have found an e.g for Windows but I am not sure how I could use that for android

```
File theFile = new File("c:/foobar.txt");
Path file = theFile.toPath();
Files.setAttribute(file, "dos:archive", false);
```

Comment: What makes you think that Android *has* a "file archive bit"?

Comment: Check this : http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29

Comment: @RIT: Thanks for the link.. but I will be having multiple file uploads taking placing and I wanted a mechanism so that the next time the user tries to upload a file again then the file must not get uploaded as it has been uploaded previously.

Comment: Above link is for your reference. You need to apply your business logic for achieving your functionality requirement.